# Git pull on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'd like to ask, if there's possibility to pull latest changes from git using Google Colab? Most answers are referring to `git clone` as the beginning of the project, but I made some minor changes and I'd like just to pull on Google Colab. Every time I get error about missing init content.

How can I pull latest changes from my git in Google Colab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to be in correct folder first - by default if you just type `git pull` it'll try to do it on root folder. First move to correct folder, where you repo was cloned and then run pull request:

```
%cd /content/repo_folder
!git pull
```

Comment: Hi, my file is not listed in this content folder. 
I saved a copy of my colab-notebook to github, this file as you know is not listed in our content folder but is just the notebook that we are using.
Hence when i do git pull, i am getting below error.
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
What i am trying to do is not to pull a repository that i cloned, but to pull the notebook itself that i saved to github. 
How to do that ? Thanks in advance.
@Michal

Comment: Open the Github notebook that you want to work with in Google Colab. Change the domain from 'github.com' to 'githubtocolab.com'. The notebook will open in Colab.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62596466/how-can-i-run-notebooks-of-a-github-project-in-google-colab