# How can I run notebooks of a Github project in Google Colab?

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

I want to run the notbooks in the following project on Github (located in notebook folder)

https://github.com/n-waves/multifit

The notebooks depend on the other modules, files and data of the whole project, so I can't just open them in google Colab. I can use `!git clone ...` to make a clone on the space provided by Colab, but then I can't open the notbooks in the browser and run them (like other notebooks run by google Colab).

So, my question is how to run those notebooks in google colab, I would prefer to run them in visual mode (I mean the browser)?

Answer (score 97):

Open the Github notebook that you want to work with in Google Colab.
Change the domain from '**github.com**' to '**githubtocolab.com**'.
The notebook will open in Colab.

Only works with Public repos.

Comment: Quite a lifehack.

Comment: This does not work for notebooks in private repositories.

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli Does anything work for private repos?

Comment: Top 10 craziest things ive seen in my life

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli You just have to give access to private repos in colab . It will ask for authentication or you can set the permission in colab home page

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is upvoted that much. It does not answer the question. In fact, `githubtocolab.com` import the notebook in colab without the dependency modules alongside the notebook.

Answer (score 20):

Another option is to browse the repository using Colab's UI. If you visit this URL, it will present you with options: 
https://colab.research.google.com/ 
[image]

Then you can select your repository:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/n-waves/multifit/blob/master/

After which, you can select the notebook you wish to open.

[image: preview]

P.S. Picked this trick up while reviewing [this PR](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/13697) for Drake.

P.P.S. I'm not yet sure how to constrain it to a certain folder ([PR comment](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/13697#pullrequestreview-450782295))

Comment: I dont understand what is next. You select the repo but open a notebook??

Comment: Sorry about that; edited text to clarify "After which, you can select the notebook ..."

Comment: This doesn't seem to check out the whole repo- maybe only the local folder? I need resources that are in a peer folder to where the notebook lives in the repo.

Comment: @EricCousineau it would be cool if you could add Robert Sim s susggestion as most people will have the need to access other data from the same repo

Comment: this question does not answer the original question, question is how to have the entire github repo in colab, and run files that depend other files

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to add `https://colab.research.google.com/github/` before the repository name in the notebook's URL. Let's say I have a Jupyter notebook on Github with the following URL: `https://github.com/username/repository/blob/master/notebook.ipynb`. To open this notebook in Google Colab, I can change the URL to `https://colab.research.google.com/github/username/repository/blob/master/notebook.ipynb`. This will open the notebook directly on Colab.

Comment: This is I believe the simplest and cleanest option

Answer (score 6):

A helpful extension is [Open in Colab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-colab/iogfkhleblhcpcekbiedikdehleodpjo?hl=en).

This will provide an icon in your browser toolbar that will open the GitHub notebook you're currently viewing in Colab.

(There's no mechanism to load notebooks from the filesystem after `!git clone ...`.)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to copy those notebooks to Google Drive. Extract their FILE_ID, then open them using

```
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/FILE_ID
```

I wrote a library to extract FILE_ID easier. It's based on `xattr`.

Here's [an example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11Ceet_vHmNoHGg8jV0V6p1aK--bxAjoO?usp=sharing) how to open a multifit notebook. `CLS-DE.ipynb`

Comment: Thank you! great job! then if I put the whole project in my drive and open a notebook from there, it can identify the paths to the project files?

Comment: The notebook will not know about other project files. You need to manually add a cell to load other files, e.g. `!npx degit n-waves/multifit -f`

Comment: I need the project files beside the notebooks. Could I mount the google drive, then open the notebook as you showed and meanwhile change the current directory (`%cd`) to the project folder in my drive and run the notebook?

Comment: There are 2 ways to do this. You can store all project files in your drive too. Then %cd to it. Or, what I prefer, is to download from github everytime to the new Colab instance. You may need to !mkdir or %cd a bit too.